# What is the best way to test javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, tdd, bdd

I'm building several jQuery plugin and going ahead I thought that will be useful to know some best practice for testing my code in order to be solid.

I usually use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) but this just for debugging.

I'd like to know the best way for doing some real test (like TDD, BDD, DDD) for my code.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: DDD, do you mean Domain Driven Design? If so this is not a testing methodology.

Comment: DDD, I mean Data Display Debugger ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Jasmine https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine and would highly recommend it.

I don't think there is a "best" framework for test your code. I just know that you "should" test your code. So with that said, just find a test/spec framework your like and get testing!

I also at times use https://github.com/webadvanced/jMoney for testing small bits of code or for testing prototype code. It displays results in the console and does not require any setup or dependent files.

If you are more of a TDD guy, you can try QUnit http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit

Comment: The best way to test code is always in production :) That said, I like qUnit very much, and don't forget to use your browser's inspector and JS console!